# How to display magento best sell and promotion product in home page page?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and I want to display best selling and promotion products on the home page.
I tried below code but it didn't work.

```
$storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
$products->setPageSize(6)->setCurPage(1);
$this->setProductCollection($products);
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Block:**

**app/code/local/{Yourpackage}/{Yourmodule}/Block/Bestsellers.php**

```
$storeId = (int) Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$date = new Zend_Date();
$toDate = $date->setDay(1)->getDate()->get('Y-MM-dd');
$fromDate = $date->subMonth(1)->getDate()->get('Y-MM-dd');

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
    ->addStoreFilter()
    ->addPriceData()
    ->addTaxPercents()
    ->addUrlRewrite()
    ->setPageSize(6);

$collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
    array('aggregation' => $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales/bestsellers_aggregated_monthly')),
    "e.entity_id = aggregation.product_id AND aggregation.store_id={$storeId} AND aggregation.period BETWEEN '{$fromDate}' AND '{$toDate}'",
    array('SUM(aggregation.qty_ordered) AS sold_quantity')
    )
    ->group('e.entity_id')
    ->order(array('sold_quantity DESC', 'e.created_at'));

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

return $collection;
```

**Template:**

**app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/template/page/html/bestsellers.phtml**

```
<div class="box best-selling">
    <h3>Best Selling Products</h3>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <?php $counter=0; foreach ($this->getBestsellerProducts() as $product): ?>
            <?php if ($counter%2 == 0): ?><tr class="<?php echo $counter%4 ? 'even' : 'odd'; ?>"><?php endif ?>
            <td>
                <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>"><img class="product-img" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(99); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" width="95" border="0" /></a>
                <div class="product-description">
                    <p><a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->stripTags($product->getName(), null, true); ?></a></p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <?php if ($counter++%2): ?></tr><?php endif ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

To display the template in your home page throught the cms->page->homepage

```
{{block type="yourmodule/bestsellers" template="page/html/bestsellers.phtml"}}
```

The complete solution in: http://inchoo.net/magento/bestseller-products-in-magento/

Comment: I try but not work also

Comment: Why it doesn't work ? What is the error ?

Comment: thanks for the answer , but i wanna know  , it which file to put  this code ?

Comment: properly, you will put it in a block, phtml then you display the phtml in home page, Look at this url, you will find more details http://inchoo.net/magento/bestseller-products-in-magento/,

Comment: can you write this code and file name

Comment: Look my update.